# What is the pseudocode for this binary tree

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, binary-tree, pseudocode

[image]

basically i am required to come out with a pseudocode for this. What i currently have is

dictionary = {} 
if node.left == none and node.right == none 
visit(node)
dictionary[node] = 1

This is only the leaf nodes, how do i get the size for each node(parent and root)?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [post-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order_(LRN)) to find the size of each node.

The idea is to first handle both left and right trees. Then, after they are processed - you can use this data to process the current node.

This should look something like:

```
count = 0
if (node.left != none)
  count += visit(node.left)
if (node.right != none)
  count += visit(node.right)
// self is included.
count += 1 
// update the node
node.size = count
return count
```

The dictionary for visited nodes is not needed since this is a **tree**, it guarantees to end.

---

As a side note - the `size` attribute of each node, is an important one. It basically upgrades your tree to a [Order Statistics Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)

Answer (score 0):

well the concept is that each node will know it's subtree size by first knowing the subtree size of all it's  child which is maximum two child here as it is a binary tree, so once it knows subtree size of all child it can then add up all of them and atlast add 1 to it's
result and then the same thing will be done by it's parent also and so on upto root node. if we think about leaf node, it 
has no child, so result subtree size will be only 1 in which it include itself.

one this idea is clear, it is easy to write code
that while traversing we will first know the subtree size of child nodes of current node then add 1 in it, in case of leaf node it will have subtree size of 1 only, below is the pseudocode of traverse funtion which finds the subtree size of each node and store them in dictionary sizeDictionary and a visited dictionary/array having larger scope has been used to keep track of visited nodes.

```
traverse(Tree curNode, dictionary subTreeSizeDictionary)
   visited[curNode] = true
   subtreeSizeDictionary[curNode] = 0
   for child of curNode
       if(notVisited[child])
           traverse(child , sizeDictionary)
           subtreeSizeDictionary[curNode] += subtreeSizeDictionary[child]
   subtreeSizeDictionary[curNode] += 1;
```

here it is binary tree, but as you can see from pseudocode this concept can be used for any valid tree, the time complexity is O(n) as we visited each node only once.